# How can I create a docker file for the below commands

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have following commands, How can I make a docker file from this

```
docker run -ti -dP --name centos -v /c/Users:/mnt/Users centos:latest /bin/bash
docker start centos
docker attach centos
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
yum install -y nodejs
```

Please help to create a dockerfile from this

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 4):

```
FROM centos:8
RUN curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
RUN yum install -y nodejs
```

Note that you can't mount volumes when building, you'll need to copy in files with the `COPY` command (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy).

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM centos:8
COPY /mnt/Users/* /bin/bash/
RUN curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
RUN yum install -y nodejs
```